# Unable to find error in Leetcode 733.Flood Fill

Tags: c++

I am getting the error below for this question in Leetcode, but I am unable to spot the error.

Question:
https://leetcode.com/problems/flood-fill/

```
class Solution {
public:  
     int visited[50][50]={0};
    vector<vector<int>> helper(vector<vector<int>>& image, int sr, int sc, int color, int c) {
        int n = image.size();
        int m = image[0].size();
        image[sc][sr] = color;
        visited[sr][sc] = 1;
        if(sr>0 and visited[sr-1][sc] == 0 and image[sr-1][sc]==c){
            helper(image, sr-1, sc, color, c);
        }
        if(sc>0 and visited[sr][sc-1] ==0 and image[sr][sc-1]==c){
            helper(image, sr, sc-1, color, c);
        }
        if(sc<m-1 and visited[sr][sc+1] ==0 and image[sr][sc+1]==c){
            helper(image, sr, sc+1, color, c);
        }
        if(sr<n-1 and visited[sr+1][sc]==0 and image[sr+1][sc]==c){
            helper(image, sr+1, sc, color, c);
        }
        return image;
    }
    
    vector<vector<int>> floodFill(vector<vector<int>>& image, int sr, int sc, int color) {
        int n = image.size();
        int m = image[0].size();
        return helper(image, sr, sc, color, image[sr][sc]);
    }
};
```

Testcase:

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
0
0
0
```

Error Message:

```
=================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x6040000000c0 at pc 0x000000346e0d bp 0x7ffdecd39d20 sp 0x7ffdecd39d18
READ of size 8 at 0x6040000000c0 thread T0
    #6 0x7f8371b800b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x6040000000c0 is located 0 bytes to the right of 48-byte region [0x604000000090,0x6040000000c0)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #6 0x7f8371b800b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c087fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c087fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c087fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c087fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c087fff8000: fa fa fd fd fd fd fd fd fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 06
=>0x0c087fff8010: fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00[fa]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==31==ABORTING
```

Comment: For the test case, is `sr=sc=0`? If so, then `visited[sr-1]` and `image[sr-1]` are out-of-bounds, for example.

Comment: Please run your program yourself in a debugger, so that you can step through it and observe the values of your variables. This will then allow you to figure out where your program logic is wrong and why the out-of-bounds access happens. Sometimes one can also perform this process on paper manually. Questions here should be (potentially) helpful also to other readers. They are not meant to substitute general debugging work for OP specifically.

Comment: Why do you return the image when it get passed in as reference? Do you intent to pipeline this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `sr` represents the current row and `sc` represents the current column.

Therefore, this line of code:

```
image[sc][sr] = color;
```

should instead be changed to:

```
image[sr][sc] = color;
```